# Data access audit log firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

How do to enable data access log and audit log for Firebase. In GCP Platform, I am able to see audit log and data access log for cloud datastore. How do we enable the same in firebase?

I have few tables in firebase, client is complaining of few calls not being serviced and has got the error in connecting. 3 requests failed out of 821 requests.

Comment: There is no accessible data access log for the Firebase Realtime Database. If you can reproduce the problem, you might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to see if they can find the missing client calls in their logs.

Comment: You have both tags firebase-relatime-database and google-cloud-firestore. Those are separate products so it may be good if you are more specific: which one do you mean? Also consider mentioning this in the title.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Could you consider moving the comment as an answer. Looks like a valid answer to me. Then we can vote on it. :)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available for firebase firestore now.
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging
Need to enable IAM audit log for Firebase API and that helps in tracking the firebase activities.

Answer (score 0):

There is no accessible data access log for the Firebase Realtime Database. If you can reproduce the problem, you might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to see if they can find the missing client calls in their logs.